# Nginx returns 404 for proxied requests, but return 200 when directly accessing

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, netlify, ghost-blog

The goal is the support mydomain.tld/blog to work with netlify where mydomain.tld is hosted.

I'm proxying from netlify `_redirects` file as following `/blog/*  http://BLOG_IP/blog/:splat 200`

I have a ghost blog on path `BLOG_IP/blog`. When I access to this URL, the blog works fine with the following Nginx access log

```
// Directly accessed
MY_IP - - [21/May/2020:15:10:29 +0000] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4935 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36"
```

When I try to go through mydomain.tld/blog I get 404 Nginx error with the following access log.

```
// Proxied through Netlify
NETLIFY_IP - - [21/May/2020:15:10:25 +0000] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36"
```

Netlify proxy works well. It's the same exact request, but somehow one is 200 other is 404. As you can see both are accessing`"GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1"` route.

Here is my Nginx config

```
server {
    server_name MY_DOMAIN;
    root /var/www/ghost/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    location ~ ^/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
server {
    if ($host = MY_DOMAIN) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name MY_DOMAIN;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

and my ghost config is

```
{
  "url": "https://MY_DOMAIN/blog",
  "server": {
    "port": 2368,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  ...
}
```

---

I have 2 questions: 
1) Why is there an inconsistency between proxied request vs direct request?
2) How can I achieve `MY_DOMAIN/blog` while using Netlify for a ghost server

Answer (score 1):

According your proxy rule at Netlify `/blog/*  http://BLOG_IP/blog/:splat 200`
You are passing BLOG_IP (direct ip address) instead of HOST header.
Therefore this rule `return 404; # managed by Certbot` is taking in place first, that's why are you getting 404.
And when you try to access directly to mydomain.tld, your browser correctly send host header to your Nginx proxy server, so the first redirect rule taking in place and you are getting 200 http code.

Probably the solution will be to change redirect rule from: 
`return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`
To:
`return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;`

Or comment out `return 404;`

Hope that will help you.